# Can't unzip file to /storage/emulated/0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, unzip

I want to unzip file.zip to /storage/emulated/0, do not create a folder. But when destPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator, it throws FileNotFoundException(Is a Directory), how can I edit my code?

```
private boolean unZip(String srcPath, String destPath, String password){
    File zip = new File(srcPath);
    try {
        net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile zipFile = new net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile(zip);
        if (!zipFile.isValidZipFile()) {
            throw new ZipException("zipFile is invalid zipFile");
        }
        if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
            zipFile.setPassword(password.toCharArray());
        }
        zipFile.extractAll(destPath);
        Log.d("destPath", destPath);
    }catch (ZipException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: did you add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE system permission in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I can unzip if I set destPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory.getPath() + File.separator + folder name, but the route will be /storage/emulated/0/folder name/file name. I want to unzip file.zip without create folder, route = /storage/emulated/0/file name.

Comment: On an Android 11 device that is not possible.

Comment: Unless app has all files access or uses saf.

Comment: It's on an Android 9 device.